# GitLaB Nginx down invalid value "+TLSv1.1" in gitlab-http.conf

Tags: ssl, nginx, gitlab, tls1.2, self-signed

I recently updated GitLab, and now GitLab's built-in Nginx server no longer starts. `/var/log/gitlab/nginx/current` continually prints the same error message:

```
nginx: [warn] invalid value "+TLSv1.1" in /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf:66
```

Here are the contents of `gitlab-http.conf:66`:

```
ssl_protocols  +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2;
```

Note that I haven't touched the GitLab configuration file and `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` completes just fine. I do typically serve my GitLab installation over SSL using a self-signed certificate, but I haven't had any issues with it in the past.

Here is the output of `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info`:

**System information**

```
System:          elementary OS 0.3.2
Current User:    git
Using RVM:       no
Ruby Version:    2.1.8p440
Gem Version:     2.5.1
Bundler Version: 1.10.6
Rake Version:    10.5.0
Sidekiq Version: 4.0.1
```

**GitLab information**

```
Version:         8.7.5
Revision:        0e8b7d8
Directory:       /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:      postgresql
Using LDAP:      no
Using Omniauth:  no
```

**GitLab Shell**

```
Version:         2.7.2
Repositories:    /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
Hooks:           /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:             /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

No one else seems to be having the same problem, and I am at a loss. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check syntax of the `ssl_protocols` directive in the documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_protocols

There are no such options as `+TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but `+TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2` are both valid options. I use them successfully on several other servers.

Comment: @Vadim Apache servers? They are valid for `SSLProtocol` directive in Apache, but nginx uses different syntax. Also note that this `warn` doesn't prevent nginx from starting. So, if you use these options on other nginx servers, then you probably have warned about them too.

Comment: I apologize. It appears you're correct. It is the plus sign `+` in front of the `TLS` directive that was causing the problem. I fixed the issue by changing `+TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2` to `TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2`. Still not sure how this change happened in the first place, but at least it is fixed. Thank you!!!